# Rails fb open graph description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

How to remove html tags from open graph description

`meta property='og:description' content="#{@post.text}"`

[image]

i have tried to add `raw` and `html_safe` to `@post.text` but it doesn't help

```
raw(@post.text) ,@post.text.html_safe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strip_tags](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) to remove tags from a string.

`strip_tags(@post.text)`

`raw` and `html_safe` will escape html characters.

html_safe: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe
raw: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw